# How to recover ~1TB data from a bricked NAS?

Tags: windows-7, linux, data-recovery, nas

I bought an IcyBox NAS a little while back, and it recently died on me.  I have physical access to the disks inside (1.5TB RAID 1 array), and the box was running a version of Linux.  I now have the difficulty of retrieving the data from the disks.  As best I can tell, the NAS uses software RAID.  All I have available are 2 Windows machines, one of which has sufficient free space to hold the data from the NAS.  I've booted one of the Windows machines into Linux using a Ubuntu CD, and Ubuntu can see the array drive(s), but cannot mount them.

What would be the quickest and easiest way to retrieve the data from the disks?  What data can I collect from Ubuntu (10.10) that will help me pin down why it can't mount the array volume?

Comment: this question seems to boil down to *"what filesystems are used by default in this device"*; once that's known, how to access it should be straightforward.  to my mind the biggest question is whether the RAID is hardware or software.

Comment: As best I can tell, the NAS uses software RAID. Viewing one of the drives using a freeware utility for Windows, the volume is listed as "Linux RAID Volume" - LVM, perhaps?  I couldn't view any of the contents of the volume using the software, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Use an external USB enclosure.  The files might be kept on a Linux file system which would be unreadable by windows, so boot up off of a Linux live CD.  You can then mount the USB device and your local hard disk (or better yet, use a 2nd external USB drive) and copy files from one file system to another.

Comment: Can Linux write to NTFS partitions safely? I was under the impression this was still quite experimental.

Comment: I think that's true, that Linux can't safely write to NTFS partitions.  Since your NAS was Linux based, I assumed it wasn't using NTFS.

Comment: @alastairs, @Marnix: Linux *can* write to NTFS partitions fairly safely, as long as you don't try to do anything stupid (like name something "NUL" or "CON" or something with a colon in it).